# Display only a part of widget in container

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve design like this.

[image: I want to achieve design like this]

How can I display only a part of the image like in container above?

As far as I know, Image widget has no built-in method to be cut out in this fashion, and generally children of the widget can't anyhow be built to exceed the boundaries. Just cut the image then?

Comment: Try with Positioned widget. You can refer this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81uanWt8W4c

Comment: @AkioAlex, See, that would work if I wanted to display the whole image. I just want to display  a part of it, like it's sticking out of the container.

Comment: @AkioAlex, oops, my apologies, the answer is exactly what you said. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: My Example]

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        right: -35,
        top: -35,
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage("assets/icon/ic_notification.png"),
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Item 1"),
          Text("Item 2"),
          Text("Item 3"),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Container(
   child: Stack(
      children : <widget>[
         Positioned(
           top : -100,
           right : -100,
           child : Image.asset("asstes/images/img1.png", fit : BoxFit.cover),              
         )
      ]
    )
)
```

You need not refer whole video. Only refer 2 minutes